# How to pass Input value as parameter in @html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass the value of a input type in a html.Actionlink so i tried the code below but it doesn't work

```
      @Html.ActionLink("EXPORT TO EXCEL", "ExportToExcel", "UserManagement", new { @class = "btn btn-primary" },
new { ugid = $("selector").val() }
```

here is my controller

```
 public void ExportToCSV(int ugid)
        {
            client.Open();
            List<UserObjUserInfo> userlistbyUGID = client.GetUserListByUGID(ugid, "token").ToList();
            client.Close();

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

            sw.WriteLine("\"USER ID\",\"USERNAME\",\"NAME\",\"CREATE DATE\"");

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Exported_Users.csv");
            Response.ContentType = "text/csv";

            foreach (var user in userlistbyUGID)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\"",
                                           user.ugid,
                                           user.username,
                                           user.name,
                                           user.CreateDate));
            }
            Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: Hope you have found your answer but I am going to provide you extension method to write values in CSV format.

Comment: try changing the position of htmlattribute and routevalues, order matters

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("EXPORT TO EXCEL", "ExportToExcel", "UserManagement", new { ugid = $("selector").val(), new { @class = "btn btn-primary" } }, this will render the following url <a href="/UserManagement/ExportToExcel?ugid=whatever">Export</a>

Comment: I already found the answer. thanks anyway
@mmushtaq do you know how to add a header text in the exported File ?

Comment: @gray try my answer, it's simpler, you are very close to getting it right

Comment: @gray See my [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004834/how-to-pass-input-value-as-parameter-in-html-actionlink/45005412#45005412). You could extend your Export functionality in this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing server side code with client side.
ActionLink is an html helper that is rendered on server and simply outputs an anchor tag. In your case it produces the following:

```
<a href="UserManagement/ExportToExcel" class="btn btn-primary">EXPORT TO EXCEL</a>
```

In your case you need client side logic to generate a correct link:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="export-btn">EXPORT TO EXCEL</a>
<input type="text" id="ugid">


$(document).ready(function(){        
    $("#export-btn").click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       window.location.href = "@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "UserManagement")" + "?ugid=" + $("#ugid").val();
    });
})
```

Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexanderar/v2uz3n5h/2/)

Comment: @JibinBalachandran i would prefer this one over mine too since this will only create the lnik on the click event  ..... I just gave him the soln not the perfect one though

Comment: @RAHULSR I appreciate the way you have accepted that.

Answer (score 1):

here the issue is that you are trying to use client side value to razer code 
you have two options here

either make a client side link instead of actionlink like

```
var link ="/UserManagement/ExportToExcel?ugid="+$("selector").val();
```

or try something like this (if you are persistant)

```
 "@Html.ActionLink("EXPORT TO EXCEL", "ExportToExcel", "UserManagement", new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })"+"?Yourparam="+$("selector").val();
```

Comment: if you look both are same answers

Comment: @RAHULSR Will this work if OP changes the value of selector after loading this page??

Comment: @JibinBalachandran yeah this will work if you place this code on change function too or just on link's click event

Answer (score 1):

If you are using view models, simply changing the position of the htmlattribute and routevalues will do

```
@Html.ActionLink("EXPORT TO EXCEL", "ExportToExcel", "UserManagement", new { ugid = item.value }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```

which will give you the following url

```
<a href="/UserManagement/ExportToExcel?ugid=whatever">EXPORT TO EXCEL</a‌​>
```

Order matters:

[LinkExtensions.ActionLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.118).aspx)

If you are generating routeattribute dynamically:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "UserManagement")' + '?ugid=' + $('#ugid').val()">EXPORT TO EXCEL</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `ActionLink` to simple html hyper link tag

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnExport">EXPORT TO EXCEL</a>
```

And add `Click` event for this `a` tag

```
 $(document).on('click', '#btnExport',function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "UserManagement")' + '?ugid=' + $("selector").val();
  })
```

Create a new class, add a method in it.

```
namespace myProject.HelperClasses
{
    public static class myExtensionClass
    {
        public static void WriteLineCSV(this StringWriter sw, params object[] Data)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var str in Data)
            {
                sb.Append(String.Format("\"{0}\",", str));
            }
            sw.WriteLine(sb);
        }
    }
}
```

In your `Controller` add `namespace`

```
using  myProject.HelperClasses
```

And add changes in your `ExportToCSV` action method

```
public class UserManagement: Controller {

    public ActionResult ExportToCSV(int ugid)
            {
                string FileName = "Exported_Users.csv";
                string FilePath = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/ExportFiles", FileName ));
                client.Open();
                List<UserObjUserInfo> userlistbyUGID = client.GetUserListByUGID(ugid, "token").ToList();
                client.Close();

                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

                sw.WriteLineCSV("USER ID","USERNAME","NAME","CREATE DATE"); //you don't need to provide "\" every tim. ext. method WriteLineCSV will do it for you.

                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Exported_Users.csv");
                Response.ContentType = "text/csv";

                foreach (var user in userlistbyUGID)
                {
                    sw.WriteLineCSV(user.ugid,user.username,user.name, user.CreateDate);
                }
                Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.End();


               return File(FilePath, "text/csv", FileName);
       }

}
```

---

You can use Extension Method `WriteLineCSV` throughout of your project and you can provide multiple parameters to it because it is accepting [param](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) array.

[Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Comment: Did you see Alex Art.'s answer. Don't you think it's the same?

Comment: Did you see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004834/how-to-pass-input-value-as-parameter-in-html-actionlink/45005412#comment76983825_45004834)

Comment: I am just extending OP Data Export functionality.